# Export database for later reimport?

Tags: java, jsf

I'm looking for a simple solution to offer some data export. I'd like to export all data belonging to the user logged in.
Further this data should be reimportable later.

What should I look for? Which approach might suit that?

many thnx

Comment: What kind of data? Structured, Semi-Structured, ...? How is the data currently stored for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom script. Only you know your data model.

MySQL will let you use INTO OUTFILE with any select query that you write. With that you can export to CSV, which is just as easy to import (LOAD DATA)